# R str_extract_all expression to extract all letters, numbers, dollar signs, single and double quotes

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I've only taken up R a few days ago and regular expressions themselves so far are more difficult than any programming language I've tried, heh...
I'm in desperate need of one, that would help me extract all sequences of letters, numbers, dollar signs, single and double quotes (last two seem to be the issue).
It is for a spam prediction project using Naive Bayes and differentiating between symbol sequences that may have single or double quotes in them is a requirement.
I'm specifically using the str_extract_all function from stringr library and must've read like 50 articles over the last two days without finding what would solve my specific problem to the point where I simply don't have time left.
Any help would be greatly appreciated and would put me a step forward in my machine learning interests.
Cheers.

Comment: Please post some sample input and desired output. Seeing an attempt or two of yours is also good so we can see what you do and don't understand.

Comment: In general, for regex, I highly recommend trying things out and debugging at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). When you have a working regex there, you can move it from there to R by doubling all the backslashes \.

Comment: And, for sample cases, 3 or 4 short sample inputs is all that is needed, as long as the cover a decent range. For example use `test = c("hello", "hello world", "hello123 wo$rld", "he'll$o!wo\"rl$25\"d", "#@$$123^'as'd")`, and show us what your desired output is for that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `regmatches` here to return all matches of your pattern within a given input string:

```
txt <- "Hello World \"how are you today\"?  Goodbye."
m <- gregexpr("[0-9A-Za-z$'\"]+", txt, perl = TRUE)
regmatches(txt, m)

[[1]]
[1] "Hello"   "World"   "\"how"   "are"     "you"     "today\"" "Goodbye"
```

### Demo

The output may not make much sense, but you did not include whitespace as being characters which are allowed in a sequence.  Hence, we are left with words, possibly having a quote on either side.

Comment: I just wrote this exact same expression for the tenth time and this time it worked... Guess it was just one of those times, where you run the same thing and for some reason it finally works. Guess that's what it's like to be a newbie at a programming language. Took me two days to figure out R Studio runs only the current line or selection, heh... Cheers.

Comment: @AudriusUžkuraitis Glad to help, drop a note if there is some other problem.